# Looking for away for my Javascript loader to activate once the submit button is pushed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a youtube mp4 and mp3 downloader website when the request is made to fetch the data from a youtube post it takes about 3-5 seconds for it to load. Where is the proper spot I can use this piece of code within my JavaScript so that it operates properly?

So far I have placed this script of code in various function within my JavaScript. None worked unless my code is wrong altogether.

//JavaScript loader waiting on youtube data

```
$("#results-list")
      .append("<li>searching for video</li>")
      .show();
```

I expect the JavaScript loader to show "Searching for video" once video data is found the JavaScript loader hides

```js
"use strict";

//truncates a string to a length with html elipses
String.prototype.trunc = function(n) {
  return this.substr(0, n - 1) + (this.length > n ? "&hellip;" : "");
};

// using apiKey for youtube api
const apiKey = "AIzaSyCGKrLxvpot6hrekFHQTPaCGeOFj92T3ao";
const searchURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search";

function formatQueryParams(params) {
  const queryItems = Object.keys(params).map(
    key => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(params[key])}`
  );
  return queryItems.join("&");
}

//Display results of youtube search
function displayResults(responseJson) {
  // if there are previous results, remove them
  console.log(responseJson);
  $("#results-list").empty();
  $("#results-list").append(
    `<li><img src="${responseJson.thumbnail}" alt="thumbnail for ${
      responseJson.title
    }" class="thumbnail"></li>`
  );
  $("#results-list").append(
    `<li><p>${responseJson.title.trunc(128)}"</p></li>`
  );

  $("#results-list").append(
    `<li class=" audio-dl"><button class="w3-button w3-black w3-round audio-dl"><a href="${
      responseJson.audio
    }" download><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Mp3 Audio Download</a></button></li>`
  );
  $("#results-list").append(
    `<li class="video-dl"><button class="w3-button w3-black w3-round video-dl"><a href="${
      responseJson.video
    }" download><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Mp4 Video Download</a></button></li>`
  );
  //display the results section
  $("#results").removeClass("hidden");
}

//initiate youtube download
function downloadVideo(videoId) {
  console.log(videoId);
  return fetch(
      `https://getvideo.p.rapidapi.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D${videoId}`, {
        headers: {
          "X-RapidAPI-Host": "getvideo.p.rapidapi.com",
          "X-RapidAPI-Key": "d390d7b0e9msh42dc09f4e07e285p1486c4jsne0a4edb9e61e"
        }
      }
    )
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      console.dir(data);
      if (!data.streams) {
        throw new Error(
          "Error retrieving download URL, try a different video!"
        );
      }
      return {
        audio: data.streams.filter(stream => {
          return stream.format === "audio only";
        })[0].url,
        video: data.streams.filter(stream => {
          return stream.format !== "audio only";
        })[0].url,
        thumbnail: data.thumbnail,
        title: data.description
      };
    });
}

function getYouTubeVideos(query) {
  const params = {
    key: apiKey,
    q: query,
    part: "snippet"
  };
  const queryString = formatQueryParams(params);
  const url = searchURL + "?" + queryString;

  console.log(url);

  $("#js-error-message").text("");

  fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      }
      throw new Error(response.statusText);
    })
    .then(responseJson => downloadVideo(responseJson.items[0].id.videoId))
    .then(download => displayResults(download))
    // .then(responseJson => displayResults(responseJson))
    .catch(err => {
      $("#js-error-message").text(`Something went wrong: ${err.message}`);
    });
}

//submit button push
function watchForm() {
  $("form").submit(event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const searchTerm = $("#js-search-term").val();
    //const maxResults = $("#js-max-results").val();
    getYouTubeVideos(searchTerm);
    console.log(searchTerm);
    $("#results-list")
      .append("<li>searching for video</li>")
      .show(); //waiting search
  });
}

$(watchForm);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Youtube video finder</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles\style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="img\logo.png" alt="logo" />
    </div>
    <nav class="dark-red"></nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="input-group">
      <div class="main">
        <h1 class="finder-heading">Download a Youtube video</h1>
        <form id="js-form">
          <label for="search-term"></label>
          <input class="search-input" type="text" name="search-term" id="js-search-term" required placeholder="       Paste link here https://youtu.be/sC11wWvQ7hE" />

          <label for="max-results"></label>

          <input class="go-button" type="submit" value="Download Now" />
        </form>
        <section class="error-results">
          <p id="js-error-message" class="error-message"></p>
        </section>
        <div class="cc-notice">
          <b>Example:</b> https://youtu.be/7_S1bxrZZOk <br />
          <b>or type a title:</b> Goalden Chyld - Focus Freestyle
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section id="results" class="hidden">
      <h2>Search result</h2>
      <ul id="results-list" class="w3-bar"></ul>
    </section>

    <section class="instruction-body">
      <div class="intstruction-content">
        <div class="instruction-head">
          <h3>How to Download Youtube Videos</h3>
          <p>
            Paste the URL of Video from YouTube or type the title of a video you want into the field above.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="instruction-box">
          <div class="instruction-box-image">
            <img src="img\Folder-Links.png" alt="twitter video downloader" width="110" height="110" />
          </div>
          <div class="instruction-box-header">
            <div class="instruction-box-heading">Copy the Video URL</div>
            <div class="instruction-box-description">
              Find the YouTube video that you want to download and copy its link.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="instruction-box">
          <div class="instruction-box-image">
            <img src="img\browser.png" alt="twitter video downloader" width="110" height="110" />
          </div>
          <div class="instruction-box-header">
            <div class="instruction-box-heading">
              Paste URL into Search Box
            </div>
            <div class="instruction-box-description">
              Next, paste the video's link into the search field above, then click the Download button.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="instruction-box">
          <div class="instruction-box-image">
            <img src="img\download-arrow.png" alt="twitter video downloader" width="110" height="110" />
          </div>
          <div class="instruction-box-header">
            <div class="instruction-box-heading">
              Download and Save Video
            </div>
            <div class="instruction-box-description">
              Click the Download button to save the Youtube video to your computer.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section></section>
  </main>
  <footer class="footer">
    <section>
      <p class="footer-right">
        Copyright © 2019 U Tube Grabber. All rights reserved.
      </p>
    </section>
    <section class="footer-left">
      <p>Created by David Piper</p>
    </section>
  </footer>
  <script src="scripts\app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @gibberish I've rolled back your edit because backticks *are* valid JavaScript; they are used to denote string templates (in which `${` and `}` are used to show replaced text. They also allow multi-line text.

Comment: Of course they can use backticks and within them multiline strings are completely fine. Your suggestion to use backslash for multiline strings comes from another language too. @gibberish